# Test for Fe2+ ion in salt using potassium hexacyanidoferrate(III)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

It's given in my book that $\ce{Fe^3+}$ ion reacts with potassium hexacyanidoferrate(III) to give brown colour.
$$\ce{Fe^3+ + [Fe(CN)6]^3- -> Fe[Fe(CN)6]}$$
Both the reactants have the same oxidation states.

**My question is, can I use the same test for $\ce{Fe^2+}$?**

First, the hexacyanidoferrate(III) will oxidize $\ce{Fe^2+}$ to $\ce{Fe^3+}$ like this:
$$\ce{Fe^2+ + [Fe(CN)6]^3- -> Fe^3+ + [Fe(CN)6]^4-}$$
Then the reaction will continue to give brown colour.

Comment: You kinda can, but the product would be different: the [Prussian blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prussian_blue), famous in its own right.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I thought prussian blue is obtained when $\ce{Fe^3+} $ reacts with hexacyanidoferrate(II) or $\ce{[Fe(CN) 6]^4-} $. I am talking about $\ce{[Fe(CN)6]^3-}$.

Comment: for prussian blue, $\ce{Fe^3+ + [Fe(CN)6]^4- -> Fe4[Fe(CN)6]3}$

Comment: $\ce{Fe^3+ + [Fe(CN)6]^4-}$ is exactly what you have on the right side of your own equation.

Comment: @IvanNeretin But can't the reactant $\ce{Fe^2+}$ combine with the product ferricyanide to give Turnbull's blue?

Comment: It's pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ce{Fe^2+}$ is oxidised to $\ce{Fe^3+}$ while $\ce{[Fe(CN)_6]^{3-}}$ is reduced to $\ce{[Fe(CN)_6]^{4-}}$. These then form the prussian blue precipitate.